# HashMap and JDK 7

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, java-7

Simple experiment has shown that `JDK7` compiled `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` uses many threads when performing simple serial insert-find benchmark:

1. Insert million numbers.
2. Search for hundreds of millions numbers.

How come? JDK7 automatically guesses how to parallelize this code??? I need to benchmark a single-threaded behavior, how could I do it?

Code, about 2.5 cores are loaded:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashSpeed {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                HashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(10000);
                final int N = 10000000;

                for (int i=1; i<N; i+=2)
                        m.put(i, i);
                for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                                if (m.get(i) != null != (i%2==1)) {
                                        System.out.println("failed");
                                }
                        }
                }
                System.out.println("TEST OK");
        }
}
```

Comment: Provide code, please, and the evidence that suggests multithreading?

Comment: This does not include the evidence that leads you to believe that it's multithreading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you verify that the `HashMap` code is actually using multiple Java threads?  From your description, it sounds like you are looking at the OS level (e.g. Task Manager for Windows).  This can be deceptive.  The **JVM** can use multiple threads, for things like garbage collection, etc.  But that doesn't mean that the Java code you are running is using multiple threads.

The easiest way to find out for sure is to look at the [OpenJDK source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) :-).

Comment: Great, that probably answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the openjdk source code (it's open source) you'd find that HashMap does not create threads.

What makes you think it does?

Comment: Because CPU is 250% loaded, you think it's not the `HashMap` but the garbage collector or something?